# assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a function which takes an extension from a string. When I try to compile the code below, I get this error:

```
excercises/12.c:8:20: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers].
```

I would be really grateful if anyone helps me.

```
int get_extension (const char *file_name, char *extension) {
    for ( ; *file_name != '.'; file_name++);
    file_name++;
    for (extension = file_name; *file_name != '\0'; file_name++, extension++) 
        *extension = *file_name;
    puts (extension);
}
```

I tried to eliminate the const, and it works, but I wanna know why it doesn't work when the const is present. Thanks in advance

Comment: You have two other problems:  your code will run off the end of the input string and fail if the file name doesn't have any `.` characters in it, and you're also not terminating the `extension` string with a `'\0'` character.

Answer (score 1):

You've assigned the pointer `extension` to have the same value as `file_name`, and then you dereference `extension` and write to it.

A `const char *` may be a string literal, but writing to a string literal invokes undefined behavior. Your code can do that, which is what the compiler is warning you about.

Answer (score 1):

At the start of the loop, you're throwing out whatever value you passed as `extension` and replacing it with the value of `file_name`.   This means that you'll be writing the extension over top of the start of the filename, which is obviously not what you want.

The warning gives a hint to this, as whatever `file_name` points to can't be changed because it is `const`, but by assigning that pointer value to `extension` it makes it so you can change it (assuming that what was passed as `file_name` is not a string literal or defined `const`, otherwise you have [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)), hence the warning.

Get rid of the assignment at the start of the loop, and also be sure to null-terminate `extension`:

```
int get_extension (const char *file_name, char *extension) {
    for ( ; *file_name != '.'; file_name++);
    file_name++;
    for (; *file_name != '\0'; file_name++, extension++) 
        *extension = *file_name;
    *extension = 0;
    puts (extension);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`file_name` is declared `const char *`, which says it points to a `char` and that you want to be advised about issues that could result in modifying the `char`.

`extension` is declared `char *`. Then `extension = file_name` attempts to assign the value of `file_name` to `extension`. This would result in `extension`, which does not have `const`, pointing to the same `char` that `file_name` points to.

This means `extension` could be used to modify that `char` without any further warning, because `*extension = foo` assigns a value to `*extension`, which is of type `char`, not `const char`. So, the compiler warns you that `extension = file_name` is attempting to assign a pointer to `const char` to a pointer to `char`, which removes the protection of the `const` qualification.

Answer (score 1):

Here you assign `extension` to the const pointer `file_name` and then formally assign new values to `*extension`:

```
for (extension = file_name; *file_name != '\0'; file_name++, extension++) 
    *extension = *file_name;
```

But because `extension` points into the `const` declared `file_name`, assigning new values is illegal and that's why toe compiler warns you and of course it is right.

I'm not sure what you want to do: As it is, the loop doesn't make sense because inside, `extension` and `file_name` always point to the same character anyway.
If you what to copy the extension to `extension` you must not reassign the pointer to `file_name`. A simple `strcpy( extension. file_name );` would do

Answer (score 1):

A constant is something that is not ought to be changed at all. When something is not a constant, then it can be changed. Now, your assignment from a constant to a non-constant reaches a paradox: on the one hand it should be change-able because of the non-constant that received the value and on the other hand the intention of the constant was not to change it. So, what actually happens is that an unchangeable and a changeable pointer point to the same thing. So, if the thing changes, then we violate the constant nature of the source.

When you encounter such issues, then the real reason of the issue is most probably in the thinking, the planning. Here, you pass `extension`, whereas in reality you want to get the extension from the input. Therefore, you do not need to pass that parameter at all. Instead, compute and return that result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *get_extension (const char *file_name) {
    for ( ; *file_name != '.'; file_name++) {
        if (*file_name == '\0') return "no extension";
    };
    file_name++;
    return (file_name);
}

int main() {
    const char * foo[4] = {"bar.php", "something.png", "idunno.video", "invalid"};
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) puts(get_extension(foo[i]));
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that the function type was changed accordingly as well, because I separated the concerns. On the one hand, you want something that determines from a filename what the extension is.

Also notice that I handled the case when the string has no extension. We need to check for the '\0' end sign to see whether the string ended before finding a dot.

Results in text format:

```
php
png
video
no extension

[Execution complete with exit code 0]
```

And a screenshot of the same:

[image]